# Hotkeys with javascript (not js/additional scripts)

Tags: javascript, hotkeys

Trying to get it to where the textarea has to be focused and then with a hotkey insert text at a specific location...

code so far..

```
function insertTextAtCursor(el, text) {
    var val = el.value, endIndex, range;
if (typeof el.selectionStart != "undefined" && typeof el.selectionEnd != "undefined") {
    var len = el.selectionEnd - el.selectionStart;
    endIndex = el.selectionEnd;
    el.value = val.slice(0, el.selectionStart) + text + val.slice(endIndex);
    el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = endIndex + (text.length - len);
    el.focus(); 
} else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && typeof document.selection.createRange != "undefined") {
    el.focus();
    range = document.selection.createRange();
    range.collapse(false);
    range.text = text;
    range.select();
 }
}

var MouseDown = false;
document.onmousedown=function(e) {
   MouseDown=true;
}
document.onmouseup=function(e) {
   MouseDown=false;
}
document.onkeydown=function(e){

if(e.which == 48 && MouseDown == true) {
    insertTextAtCursor(inputbox, 'Zero');
    }
}
```

if I put the function in a button with the onClick event it works... but wanting a hotkey...if i remove the function and put an alert it works??

Comment: what is `inputbox` in the onkeydown function? and, why is the mouse state important for a "hotkey" function? That makes no sense at all

Comment: inputbox is the textarea that you type into.  I wanted to make it where you click and hold the mouse button down where you wanted to insert the text.  This also prevents overwriting the actual key if needed, but i can't get the function to run from there, it only works on the onClick events on buttons

Comment: no, inputbox is a javascript variable, i was wondering what it's value was, but have lost all interest now

Comment: <textarea rows="30" cols="88" NAME="inputbox"></textarea> when the page loads its empty

Comment: found out you can't use just inputbox... you have to use     `document.getElementById('inputbox')`